# Django: Add and Subtract from inventory in models

Tags: python, django, django-models, inventory

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be simple, but it has proven a bit challenging for me right now.

I am trying to build a simple ATM system for Banknotes in Django 1.11 and Python 3.6.

I basically need to keep track of banknotes that are in stock and how many of each kind. But I realized that using the logic that I'm accustomed with I only create new instances of the model instead of adding to the quantity fields.

I know how to use a quantity field to add items of an order (but thats also creating a new instance of an order), but how can I do it to make changes to an inventory without creating a new instance of it?

I guess it should have something to do with ManyToManyField and the through argument. I'm also not sure if I should separate each Banknote as one Class or put them all under a single Class.

Any ideas?

Here's my model:

```
class Cedula(models.Model):
    um          = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    dois        = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    cinco       = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    dez         = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    vinte       = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    cinquenta   = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    cem         = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Cédula"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cédulas"
```

Comment: all you have will be a single row which will get updated each time when some change occurs in the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks fine in your model. You will have just a single row which will get be updated after it gets created first.

Firstly create the object of Cedula

```
from app.models import Cedula
cedula = Cedula()
cdeula.save() # This will instantiate the row with all entries 0.
```

For updating you have to perform this

```
from app.models import Cedula
from django.db.models import F
cedula = Cedula.objects.all()[0]
cedula.dios = F('dios')+ 2 # Here adding 2 or any number which you want to update with
cedula.vinte = F('vinte') -5 # Here subtracting with 5 or again number which you want to update with
cedula.save()
```

Usually for the models which don't have much relational things to do or single entries in them it is best to create their object in a seprate start script and run them before running your server. So that database can populate the content before.